# D365 F&O Add field to Expense Journal Lines that is available in Invoice Proposal

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, x++

I want to add a field to the Project Expense Journal Lines that will store a reference piece of data and have it be available in the Invoice Proposal selection/Expense lines. Through the UI I can see where I can add a field to the Project Expense Journal Lines but it’s not available on the project invoice proposal.

We're using 10.0.38 D365 Finance and Operations - Project management and accounting. Ultimately we'll be integrating our expense software into the expense module but I need a place to store the expense report. Description is already being utilized for transaction detail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried utilizing all of the available text fields on the expense journal line to see if any of them can be repurposed to this end, but none of them transfer onto the invoice proposal screen where our administrators do most of their work. (Also frustrating that those fields can be filled out but don't go anywhere useful...)